# ATS - What is the constraint C3NSTRprop(C3TKmain(); S2Eeqeq(S2Eintinf(0); S2Evar(abc(4303)))) referring to?

Tags: ats, proof-of-correctness

I have the following ATS code:

```
extern prfun mul_nx0_0 {n:int} (): MUL(n, 0, 0)

extern prfun mul_nx1_n {n:int} (): MUL(n, 1, n)

extern prfun mul_neg_1 {m,n,p:int} (MUL(m, n, p)): MUL(~m, n, ~p)

extern prfun mul_neg_2 {m,n,p:int} (MUL(m, n, p)): MUL(m, ~n, ~p)

extern prfun mul_assoc {a,b,c,ab,bc,abc:int}
( MUL(a, b, ab)
, MUL(b, c, bc)
, MUL(ab, c, abc)
): MUL(a, bc, abc)

primplmnt mul_assoc {a,b,c,ab,bc,abc:int} (pf1, pf2, pf3) =
let
    prfun mul_assoc1 {a,b,c,ab,bc,abc:nat} .<a>.
    (pf1: MUL(a, b, ab), pf2: MUL(b, c, bc), pf3: MUL(ab, c, abc)) : MUL(a, bc, abc) =
    case+ pf1 of
        | MULbas()     => MULbas()
        | MULind(pf1') =>
            case+ pf2 of
                | MULbas()     => mul_nx0_0 {a} ()
                | MULind(pf2') =>
                    case+ pf3 of
                        | MULbas()     =>
                            sif a == 0
                            then MULbas()
                            else mul_nx0_0 {a} ()
                        | MULind(pf3') => MULind(mul_assoc1(pf1', pf2', pf3'))
in
    sif a < 0
    then let
        prval _pf1 = mul_neg_1(pf1)
        prval _pf3 = mul_neg_1(pf3)
    in
        sif b < 0
        then let
            prval __pf1 = mul_neg_2(_pf1)
            prval _pf2  = mul_neg_1(pf2)
            prval __pf3 = mul_neg_1(_pf3)
        in
            sif c < 0
            then let
                prval __pf2  = mul_neg_2(_pf2)
                prval ___pf3 = mul_neg_2(__pf3)
            in
                MULneg(mul_assoc1(__pf1, __pf2, ___pf3))
            end
            else MULneg(mul_neg_2(mul_assoc1(__pf1, _pf2, __pf3)))
        end
        else MULneg(mul_assoc1(_pf1, pf2, _pf3))
    end
    else sif b < 0
        then sif c < 0
            then let
                    prval _pf1 = mul_neg_2(pf1)
                    prval _pf2 = mul_neg_1(mul_neg_2(pf2))
                    prval _pf3 = mul_neg_1(mul_neg_2(pf3))
                in
                    mul_assoc1(_pf1, _pf2, _pf3)
                end
            else let
                    prval _pf1 = mul_neg_2(pf1)
                    prval _pf2 = mul_neg_2(pf2)
                    prval _pf3 = mul_neg_2(pf3)
                in
                    MULneg(mul_assoc1(_pf1, _pf2, _pf3))
                end
        else sif c < 0
            then let
                    prval _pf2 = mul_neg_1(pf2)
                    prval _pf3 = mul_neg_1(pf3)
                in
                    MULneg(mul_assoc1(pf1, _pf2, _pf3))
                end
            else mul_assoc1(pf1, pf2, pf3)
end

implement main0 () = ()
```

The motivation of the code is to complete a simple exercise using the dependent type system: to prove that multiplication of integers is associative. The idea of the proof is to break the 3 integer variables, a,b,c, into the possible cases for their signs, and then reduce the problem to proving associativity for multiplication of natural numbers, where we can use induction.

Mathematically, this strategy ought to be sound (although breaking down the cases and making a huge decision tree was tedious). The problem is, when I try to compile the above file using the command `patscc assoc.dats`, I get the following error message:

```
assoc.dats: 591(line=20, offs=27) -- 599(line=20, offs=35): error(3): unsolved constraint: C3NSTRprop(C3TKmain(); S2Eeqeq(S2Eintinf(0); S2Evar(abc(4303))))
typechecking has failed: there are some unsolved constraints: please inspect the above reported error message(s) for information.
exit(ATS): uncaught exception: _2tmp_2ATS_2dPostiats_2src_2pats_error_2esats__FatalErrorExn(1025)
```

Frankly, I have no idea how to interpret this error message. What is the constraint `C3NSTRprop(C3TKmain(); S2Eeqeq(S2Eintinf(0); S2Evar(abc(4303))))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with the current code. For instance, the following
case does not work:

```
   case+ pf1 of
        | MULbas()     => MULbas()
```

because abc==0 has not be proven yet. This can be readily fixed as follows:

```
   case+ pf1 of
        | MULbas()     => let prval MULbas() = pf3 in MULbas() end
```

I would not suggest to continue with the current proof code.

In general, if you want to prove theorems involving MUL from the first principle, then you almost always need the following two proof functions:

```
extern
prfun
mul_is_tot
{a,b:int}() : [c:int] MUL(a, b, c)

extern
prfun
mul_is_fun
{a,b,c1,c2:int}
( pf1: MUL(a, b, c1)
, pf2: MUL(a, b, c2)): [c1==c2] void
```

By the way, the following implementation of mul_assoc passes type-checking:

```
extern
prfun
mul_is_tot
{a,b:int}() : [c:int] MUL(a, b, c)

extern
prfun
mul_is_fun
{a,b,c1,c2:int}
( pf1: MUL(a, b, c1)
, pf2: MUL(a, b, c2)): [c1==c2] void

extern
prfun
mul_distrib
{a,b,c,ac,bc:int}
( MUL(a, c, ac)
, MUL(b, c, bc)): MUL(a+b, c, ac+bc)

extern
prfun
mul_assoc
{a,b,c,ab,bc,abc:int}
( pf1: MUL(a, b, ab),
  pf2: MUL(b, c, bc),
  pf3: MUL(ab, c, abc)): MUL(a, bc, abc)

extern
prfun
mul_neg_1
{m,n,p:int}(MUL(m, n, p)): MUL(~m, n, ~p)

primplmnt
mul_assoc
{a,b,c
,ab,bc,abc:int}
(pf1, pf2, pf3) =
(
sif
(a >= 0)
then
mul_assoc1(pf1, pf2, pf3)
else
mul_neg_1(mul_assoc1(mul_neg_1(pf1), pf2, mul_neg_1(pf3)))
) where
{
prfun
mul_assoc1
{a:nat
;b,c,ab,bc,abc:int} .<a>.
( pf1: MUL(a, b, ab),
  pf2: MUL(b, c, bc),
  pf3: MUL(ab, c, abc)): MUL(a, bc, abc) =
(
case+ pf1 of
| MULbas() =>
  let
  prval MULbas() = pf3 in MULbas()
  end
| MULind(pf1') => // a = a'+1 // ab = a'b + b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  let
  prval pf3' = mul_is_tot() // (a'*b)*c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  prval res' = mul_assoc1(pf1', pf2, pf3') // (a'*b)*c = a'*(b*c)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  prval (  ) = mul_is_fun(pf3, mul_distrib(pf3', pf2))
  in
    MULind(res')
  end
)
} (* end of [mul_assoc] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The constraint is saying that the type checker can not prove that static variable `abc` (with a stamp 4303) equals to `0`. `S2E` is a prefix that means a static expression at level 2 (among multiple levels of translation.)

Based on the line number of the message, you probably need something like `MULprop_m_0_p_0` from https://www.cs.bu.edu/~hwxi/ATS/TUTORIAL/contents/dataprops.dats.